# Node red how to take the attribute in array json

Tags: node-red

I need to get the age of the people to do some validation, how can i access to the field age in the json in node red?

```
 {
        "People": [
            {
                "NAME":"HK",
                "Age":"16"
            },
            {
               "NAME":"CK",
                "Age":"16" 
            },{
                "NAME":"DK",
                "Age":"16"
            }
        ]

    }
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: var peopleArray=[];

for(var i=0; i<2;i++){
         peopleArray ={ payload:msg.payload.people[i]};
}

 
return people;

Comment: Edit the question, don't try and add code as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code in a Function node will take the given input and output a message for each element in the `People` array

```
var array = [];
for (var i=0; i<msg.payload.People.length;i++) {
  array.push({payload: msg.payload.People[i]});
}

return array;
```

You can then access the age in each of those messages in the following nodes as `msg.payload.age`

If you just want to check the whole array in the fist function node then something like:

```
for (var i=0; i<msg.payload.People.length;i++) {
  if (msg.payload.People[i].age < 16) {
      //do something here
  }
}
```